# Error trying to reinstall rpm java package

Tags: java, rpm

I am trying to reinstall java on a CentOS box with the following command (Is this the best command?):

```
rpm -i --force /root/jdk-6u11-linux-i586.rpm
```

But I get errors when doing this:

```
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/jsse.pack
        charsets.jar...
etc.....
```

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Removed all rpm -qa java packages and then reinstalled using the .bin file, seems okay now

Comment: I remember that installing an RPM that was already installed threw an error if you used -i, yet you could happily upgrade a package that wasn't already installed with -U. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice that RPM gives you a reason for the problem.

Run

```
# strace -e file -f rpm -i --force /root/jdk-6u11-linux-i586.rpm
```

and see what the error is.

(Isn't the recommended flags `-Uvh` for installing packages with RPM?)

Answer (score 0):

afaik u means upgrade.

-hiv was my favorite, scnr :)

Answer (score 0):

Removed all rpm -qa java packages and then reinstalled using the .bin file, seems okay now.